# Java ImageIO: Exception Weirdness

Tags: java, exception, io, ioexception, filenotfoundexception

In my application I was trying to save a `BufferedImage` to a PNG file using `ImageIO`. The file is chosen by the user so I need to react to errors that might happend (e.g. user tries to save in a location he has no write permission for). However I am unable to catch the `IOException` that occurs.

The following code shows the problem. Trying to save to "/foo" should throw an exception for most users on *nix systems, since they do not have write permission in the root directory.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class IOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(640, 480,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        try {
            File f = new File("/foo");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught IOException!");
        }
    }
}
```

However, the exception is not caught. Output:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /foo (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(FileImageOutputStream.java:69)
    at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(FileImageOutputStreamSpi.java:55)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:419)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1530)
    at IOTest.main(IOTest.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1538)
    at IOTest.main(IOTest.java:16)
```

Note that `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException` so it should get caught. A second catch block did not help either:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Caught FileNotFoundException!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Caught IOException!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stems from the details of `ImageIO` implementation. You will circumvent the problem if you don't pass the `File` instance to `ImageIO.write`, but first try to open a `FileOutputStream` yourself and pass that to `write`.

This is a more precise analysis of what happens in `ImageIO.write`. [Line 1530](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java#1530):

```
stream = createImageOutputStream(output);
```

[Line 1538](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java#1538):

```
stream.close();
```

And if you take a look at the implementation of `createImageOutputStream`, you'll see several code paths that return `null`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `ImageIO.write` method prints the `IOException` but really doesn't handle it and ends with a `NullPointerException`. In this specific case of a buggy library, maybe you *should* catch any `RuntimeException`...

Of course it will be better to test before if the directory exists and [is writable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ImageIO.write()` wraps the `FileNotFoundException` into a `NullPointerException`.

You should catch `NullPointerException`, or better check file existence before invoking `ImageIO.write()`.

Comment: There is no "caused by" to justify your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it the FileNotFoundException is being handled within javax.imageio.ImageIO.write and that failure is causing a null pointer exception.  Try to check the file permissions before you try saving it!